# Find things within drawn area on Bing maps

Tags: silverlight-4.0, bing-maps

I am currently using Bing maps and I make an area by drawing a rectangle on Bing maps. I want to search for a set of restaurants within that area. Is this possible at all in Bing maps ? If not, what would be the closest/nearest workaround to this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that there are two solution depending of the way you get data.

If you are querying an SQL database, you could use the geographic type and use the method STIntersect to get only the restaurants in you rectangle.

Else, just look at the [Bing Maps Search Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980960.aspx) and you will find what you want.

Hope it Help .